# Apply width and height styling to div background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am using a background image for my top "heading" `div` section of my website. It was drawn on CorelDrawX6 and exported to a .jpg image, meaning I can't set the height and width exactly right when exporting. What I want to achieve is have the webpage scale the background image to the right height. I want to have `height:150px; width:100%`, but because it is applied to the `div` like this:

```
<div style = "height:150px;background-image:url('Design.jpg');">
```

I can't apply styling directly to the image. Does anyone have a solution?

P.S. I have checked out many of the "related questions" and have not found an answer. Also, please bear in mind I want a background image for one div, not the whole page (which would be a lot easier).

Current situation:
[image: current situation:]

My desired situation is to have the full image as a background (the current image is a scaled-up version, the real image (which I could not upload) looks the same but has text on, and the light blue bar is much smaller).

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the `background-size` property …?

Comment: If none of these answers are useful, it may be worth providing a simple image showing your current situation and your desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

HTML

```
<div class="lorem" alt="lipsum" title="lorem lipsum">
  <img class=ImgLorem></img>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.lorem{

}
.ImgLorem{

}
.lorem img{
  background: url(Design.jpg);  
  height:150px;
  width:100%;
}
```

this should work.

Let me know.

Comment: or try background-size:cover;

Comment: so to get your question straight, you want your image to resize into the 150px height even if the image height is bigger?

Comment: Ok this should work for you : http://jsfiddle.net/kECPx/ You do need js to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you looking for?

```
background-size: auto 150px;
```

Comment: I want width property set to 100% and height to 150px. Will this be possible?

Comment: @imulsion if you want to keep scale of the image then no. But you can set ex. div size width: 300px height: 150px and background-size: auto 150px;

Comment: nope, didn't work. I will edit my quetion with current situation and desired situation.